# How do I display UTF-8 characters sent through a websocket?

Tags: python, utf-8, websocket

I'm trying to build a simple web socket server that loads a file with some tweets in it (as CSV) and then just sends the string of the tweet to a web browser through a websocket. [Here is a gist with the sample that I'm using for testing.](https://gist.github.com/ccheaton/8655468) Here's the [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) server component (`server.py`):

```
import random
import time
from twisted.internet   import reactor
from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory, \
                               WebSocketServerProtocol, \
                               listenWS


f = open("C:/mypath/parsed_tweets_sample.csv")

class TweetStreamProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def sendTweet(self):
        tweet = f.readline().split(",")[2]
        self.sendMessage(tweet, binary=False)

    def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
        self.sendTweet() 

if __name__ == '__main__':

   factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000", debug = False)
   factory.protocol = TweetStreamProtocol
   listenWS(factory)
   reactor.run()
```

And here is the web component (`index.html`):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000");

            ws.onmessage = function(e) {
               document.getElementById('msg').textContent = e.data; //unescape(encodeURIComponent(e.data));
               console.log("Got echo: " + e.data);
            }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h3>Twitter Stream Visualization</h3>
      <div id="msg"></div>
      <button onclick='ws.send("tweetme");'>
         Get Tweet
      </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

When the tweet arrives in the browser, the UTF-8 characters aren't properly displayed. How can I modify these simple scripts to display the proper UTF-8 characters in the browser?

Comment: Perhaps your default font doesn't have the unicode/utf-8 code points that you are trying to display?

Comment: Try `self.sendMessage(u"\u03C0".encode("utf8"), binary = False)` and check if you get a greek "pi" displayed in browser.

Comment: @oberstet Yep, that comes through as a pi character. However, if I switch the line to be `self.sendMessage(tweet.encode("utf8"), binary=False)` I get the error `exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 138: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
                                       WebSocketServerFactory


class TweetStreamProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

   def sendTweets(self):
      for line in open('gistfile1.txt').readlines():
         ## decode UTF8 encoded file
         data = line.decode('utf8').split(',')

         ## now operate on data using Python string functions ..

         ## encode and send payload
         payload = data[2].encode('utf8')
         self.sendMessage(payload)

      self.sendMessage((u"\u03C0"*10).encode("utf8"))

   def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
      if payload == "tweetme":
         self.sendTweets()



if __name__ == '__main__':

   import sys

   from twisted.python import log
   from twisted.internet import reactor

   log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

   factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000", debug = False)
   factory.protocol = TweetStreamProtocol

   reactor.listenTCP(9000, factory)
   reactor.run()
```

Notes:

- above code is for [Autobahn|Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahn) 0.7 and above
- I'm not sure if you sample Gist is properly UTF8 encoded file
- However, the "last" pseudo Tweet is 10x "pi", and that properly shows in the browser, so
  it works in principle ..

Also note: for reasons too long to explain here, Autobahn's `sendMessage` function expects `payload` to be already UTF8 encoded if `isBinary == False`. A "normal" Python string is Unicode, which needs to be encoded like above to UTF8 for sending.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I don't think that the source file is encoded improperly, but I suspect that some of the Unicode characters (which I think are UTF-8?) are outside of the normal character map for UTF-8. The odd thing is that they display when the file is imported into Excel as UTF-8, but won't display when brought in through python.

Comment: UTF8 is an _encoding_ for Unicode, and it is able to encode any Unicode code point.

Answer (score 0):

instead of  `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><` try `<meta charset = utf-8>`.
if you're using XHTML then write `<meta charset = utf-8 />`

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't really seem to help, though.